# Bind mounting Spring micro-services with Docker results in Eureka not discovering other services

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

I had previously built a Docker image of each Spring micro-service, and in the `docker-compose.yml` file this is what I did to start them and have some other services being registered by Eureka's service, by overriding `defaultZone` passing the container's name:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  eureka-discovery:
    image: eureka-discovery-service:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 8761:8761

  zuul-gateway:
    image: zuul-gateway-service:0.0.1
    environment:
      - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-discovery:8761/eureka
    depends_on:
      - eureka-discovery
    ports:
      - 8765:8765
```

It worked. Now, I did things a little different, by bind mounting my project into a container for local development:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  eureka-discovery-service:
    container_name: eureka-discovery-service
    image: openjdk:11.0.9.1-jdk
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    volumes:
      - ./eureka-discovery-service:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    command: ./mvnw spring-boot:run

  zuul-gateway-service:
    container_name: zuul-gateway-service
    image: openjdk:11.0.9.1-jdk
    environment:
      - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-discovery-service:8761/eureka
    ports:
      - 8765:8765
    volumes:
      - ./zuul-gateway-service:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    command: ./mvnw spring-boot:run
    depends_on:
      - eureka-discovery-service
    links:
      - eureka-discovery-service
```

But with things like this, `zuul-gateway-service` doesn't see `eureka-discovery-service` like it did before.

> 2020-12-17 23:26:29.997 ERROR 78 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ZUUL-GATEWAY-SERVICE/7c580b412063:zuul-gateway-service:8765 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

I notice that it's using the Eureka container's ID instead of its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by altering the `command` and overriding the property there instead of on `environments`:

```
command: ./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-discovery-service:8761/eureka
```

If there'd be a better way, I'd like to know.